# Find the degree of splitting field of $x^3-x+1$ over $\mathbb{F_3}$

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let  $f(x)=x^3-x+1$ over $\mathbb{F_3}$

$\mathbb{F_3}$ is the finite field of order $3$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_3}$.

$f(x)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z_3}$

Since it is a degree 3 polynomial, showing it has no roots in $\mathbb{Z_3}$ is enough to show it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z_3}$

So the splitting field is $\dfrac{\mathbb{F_3}[x]}{\langle f(x) \rangle}$, where $\langle f(x) \rangle$ is the ideal generated by $f(x)$, which is a maximal ideal since $f(x)$ is irreducible, making this a field.

Now, setting $f(x)=0$, we get $x^3=x-1$ so $x^3$ and its higher powers can be replaced by $1,x,x^2$ in this field. So elements of this field are of the form $ax^2+bx+c+\langle f(x) \rangle$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z_3}$. So number of elements in this field is $3^3=27$, which is the required degree.

Is this correct?

Comment: It's an Artin-Schreier equation...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm not familiar with those. I have to find the splitting field using the basics.

Comment: I'm the `\langle, \rangle` fairy, here to let you know that $\langle,\rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than $<, >$ does :)

Comment: Yes you are correct. The field is $$\{a+bx^2+cx^3\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb F_3\}$$ which is a field with $27$ elements. And the degree extension is indeed $3$ (since $x^3-x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_3$).

Comment: Hint If $\alpha$ is one of the roots of the polynomial, then $\alpha+1$ and $\alpha+2=\alpha-1$ are the other two. (This is basic Artin-Schreier stuff).

Comment: Your last sentence sounds like you think $27$ is the degree. I don't know whether it's language or a slight misunderstanding of the definition of degree that causes it, but it is wrong. The degree is the exponent $3$ instead.